# How do you read the selected options from Select2?

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I have a simple HTML form that uses Select2:

```
<form action="{{  url('newtasting') }}" id="tasting-form" method="POST">
<select2 name="variety" id="variety" v-model="form.variety">
```

Using Laravel, I POST my html form to routes page: (web.php)

```
Route::post('newtasting', 'DatabaseController@insert');
```

Which then passes the information to my DatabaseController:

```
public function insert(Request $formData)
{
    DB::insert('insert into tastings (user_id, variety_id, region_id, vintage_id, brand_id, colour_intensity, hue, viscosity, aroma, sweetness, acidity, tannin, alcohol, body, overall, created_at, updated_at, flavour, notes) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
        [auth()->user()->id, $formData->variety, $formData->region, $formData->vintage, $formData->brand, $formData->colour_intensity, $formData->hue, $formData->viscosity, $formData->aroma, $formData->sweetness, $formData->acidity, $formData->tannin, $formData->alcohol, $formData->body, $formData->overall, date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d"), $formData->flavour, $formData->notes]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**From the error log:**

```
insert into tastings (user_id, variety_id, region_id, vintage_id, brand_id, colour_intensity, hue, viscosity, aroma, sweetness, acidity, tannin, alcohol, body, overall, created_at, updated_at, flavour, notes) 
values (2, , , , , 9, 9, 9, , , 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2018-06-21 14:45:31, 2018-06-21 14:45:31, , notes))
```

As you can see, I'm able to read a variable such as $formData->colour_intensity as it's only a range slider with values 0-9.

But I can't seem to read the variables from the select2's. There are 6 of them in the form.

I just want to save the selected options' ID into the database with the rest of the information.

Comment: Where is the error message? how you use select2 in your form paste the blade file also?

Comment: There is no error message per say. But referencing $POST['select-2-id'] isn't sufficient.